# What problems or difficulties can a beginner have in Linux?

Tags: linux

I would like to ask a question, I'm learning to program websites, currently learning javascript. And I was interested in entering the Linux world (Windows can sometimes be a sad experience) and researching some good linux distros for programming I found an excerpt in the article saying the following:

> Another important tip is to find out if the distribution you intend to
> use has a good base of active users and a wide community, that way,
> it's easier for you to find the solution to your problems on the
> internet.

In addition to this excerpt, I found several other references to "problems" that a developer can have in linux. Some references to System Updates was one of them...

I Would like to know what problems a developer/beginner might encounter with Linux?

Comment: Simply browse U&L_SE and you will get the only possible answer : **ANY**. Not that just beginners can face any problem. Any one can face any problem. The real question is how long will these problems take to solve and since most of the problems anyone can face are documented, you need a distribution with great documentation and… a great community of  users likely to provide answers different from… RTFM… ;-)

Comment: BTW the worse problems are hardware compatibility problems therefore first ensure that every part of your system+peripherals are well supported.

Comment: You're asking for a list of things. See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) Your question is an invitation for distinct partial answers that are equally valid; it does not fit the site.

Comment: @MC68020 Got it, it was an unnecessary fear so thanks for the explanation, do you have any linux distro tips for a beginner to get started? Preferably that comes without many packages installed, i use visual studio code a lot!

Comment: Linux is user friendly, but it is quite selective about the users it chooses to befriend. You gotta put the work in, and then you will get the results.  It's _wife_ material. Windows is a lot more easy access.  Easy on the eye, but it is high maintenance, flighty, unreliable, and generally annoying. It's like that girlfriend you had in high school -- great looks, but a bit of a nightmare long-term, and therefore not really good relationship material.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I wouldn't qualify it like that, maybe for you it's really that... but for those who are beginners it's a very common doubt, on youtube even Linux videos treat the system as if it were something extremely complex to use, and that added to the various linux distros each with their own characteristics.. it made me doubt if I could find certain errors, problems with updates that would stop something... something like that.. that's why the question

Comment: "It's like that girlfriend you had in high school -- great looks, but a bit of a nightmare long-term" - Perfect @Brad Just to clarify the reason for wanting to leave windows: Today there was an update... as soon as it finished, in the menu to shut down the computer, some options appeared: Suspend, Update and shutdown, Shut down, Update and restart, Restart... I clicked restart... the computer started to update... it made me very angry, imagine if this happens in a company? Companies usually have PCs with simpler configurations (like my PC). And today this update took about 1 hour...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Problems" is a wide term. But, in short, these problems will come down to the amount of knowledge you have, or can accumulate, in order for these "problems" to be solved or avoided.

A *lot* depends on the distro you pick here. If you are a newbie, I'd go for a *common* distro, known for stability and/or ease-of-use to minimise the chance of problems, and maximise the chance of documented solutions
(e.g.: Ubuntu, ZorinOS, Debian). Once you get more experienced, you can contemplate more cutting-edge distros (Fedora, Arch, Gentoo, etc).

In terms of the *type* of problems, you might encounter, they are broadly, in my opinion, the following:

- **Usability** -- how do you do something that you could do in Windows, on Linux? This is often about what Windowing system you use (X, Wayland) and what windows manager you use (Gnome, KDE, XFCE, i3, etc).
- **Driver/hardware support and configuration** -- how do you make your specific hardware work with Linux? This can be tricky, but, these days, if you have modern, and reasonably standard hardware and peripherals, then you should be okay -- otherwise, expect some research.
- **Troubleshooting problems** -- this often means getting comfortable in the terminal which will require that you become proficient with command line tools, shells, etc. This is arguably the biggest learning area and you can reasonably expect a life-long learning journey here (I've been running linux since the mid 90s and I'm still learning)
- **Productivity** -- how can you make your Linux user experience efficient?  Doing things faster, configuring things in a custom way to make your life easier, automating things for a better quality of life. This moves you into the realm of scripting and, ultimately, programming, which has its own set of learning curves and "problems" that come with it.
- **Software selection** -- how can you find the right software you need to fulfil the computing needs you have? This depends on what you want to be doing on Linux -- as a programmer, you are probably going to be okay, but as a graphics designer, music producer, business professional, IT security researcher, etc, there are other considerations or "problems" that you'll need to face here.

Comment: @edvaldo-filho I'd suggest ZorinOS for your use case and level of experience. I just upgraded my 12 year old daughter from a Mac to Zorin and it is very easy to use and easy to maintain. It's based on Ubuntu which has a huge community, and is optimised for those coming from Windows/MacOS

Comment: I was going to install another distro but I had a look at the ZorinOS website and it looked really interesting.. thanks a lot! I marked it as the best answer, since you were the only one who pointed out all the details before choosing the distro, important details that many blogs that make lists of "best distros to code" do not include.. perfect! I know that for many who have more knowledge it may seem like a trivial question, but for those who are starting your answer clarifies well what to take into account when choosing the system, I did not find 1 blog that mentioned these considerations!

Comment: Thanks!  Good luck with it. I think you'll find ZorinOS really nice. It has a great UX and good software library, so getting your web-dev stuff (VSCode), etc running on it should be straighforward.